# Significance of question mark in Java cron

Tags: java, cron

Source Wikipedia:

> **Question mark** (?) is used instead of '*' for leaving either day-of-month or day-of-week blank.

The above statement is not making much sense to me.

So if I write some cron as **`0 0 0 ? * *`** then does it mean first of every month or it means it will execute daily?

It is a bit confusing as Java crons start with seconds while other crons start with minute.

Answer (score 153):

According to the [Quartz CronTrigger tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html) (Quartz is used by www.cronmaker.com, referenced above), the `?` wildcard is only used in the day of month and day of week fields:

> ? ("no specific value") - useful when you need to specify something in one of the two fields in which the character is allowed, but not the other. For example, if I want my trigger to fire on a particular day of the month (say, the 10th), but don't care what day of the week that happens to be, I would put "10" in the day-of-month field, and "?" in the day-of-week field.

I guess `*` isn't appropriate here because `*` means execute on every day of the week, which contradicts the rule saying that it should only run on the 10th of the month.

Comment: In Spring Boot quartz CronExpression.isValidExpression("0 * * * * *") return false, CronExpression.isValidExpression("0 * * * * *") return true, but In Spring Boot scheduling tasks  both of  @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *") or @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?") work fine

Answer (score 1):

`?` mark means there is no specific value set for that field. So `0 0 0 ? * *` means respectively run at,

1. the start of the second (00 seconds)
2. the start of the minute (00 minutes)
3. the start of the hours (00 hours)
4. don't care about the day of the month
5. every month
6. every day

`0 0 0 ? * *` - Fire at 12pm every day of every month at midnight (00:00:00)

Answer (score -3):

I know it's an old question but for posterity, it's explained here : http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm#STARTTIME

> Both in classic and extended modes, nnCron users can use a
>   "nonstandard" character "?" in the first four fields of cron format.
>   It stands for time of nnCron startup, i. e. when a field is processed,
>   startup time will be substituted for the question mark: minutes for
>   Minute field, hour for Hour field, day of the month for Day of month
>   field and month for Month field.
>
> For example, if you write the following:
>
> Time: ? ? * * * * the task will be executed on nnCron startup and then
>   will be executed daily at the same time (unless the user doesn't
>   restart nnCron, of course): question marks will be "replaced" by
>   nnCron startup time. For example, if nnCron was started at 8:25,
>   question marks will be substituted this way:
>
> Time: 25 8 * * * *

Comment: nnCron has nothing to do with Java Cron and the meaning of ? there is completely different than the meaning in Java.