# Spring Scheduled cron job

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

I need two cron jobs and I am really not sure if I am doing right. One con job should run every 01.01.xxx at 01:00 o'clock and the other should run every night at 01:00.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 01 01 01 ?") // every year 01.01 at 01:00 o'clock
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 01 * * *") // very day at 01:00 o'clock
```

Are these the correct expression?

Comment: Use this to verify or generate any cron expression http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: I have tried this website and the calculator works fine. But I would have one more question converning this calculator: The expressions have 7 digets but @Scheduled only must have 6 digits. How do I handle than. This doe not work because of 7 digits: **@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 1/1 * ? *")**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The pattern is a list of six single space-separated fields: representing second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday. Month and weekday names can be given as the first three letters of the English names.

Every day syntax is "sec min hour * * *"

Once a year syntax is "sec  min  hour  day_of_month  month ?"

(Normally "01" is written as "1")

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

[Spring cron expression for every day 1:01:am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147044/spring-cron-expression-for-every-day-101am)