# A better way to run task periodically in Java

Tags: java, spring, unix, cron

I have a method that I want to be invoked periodically: every day on 11 am. It is a simple method in Main:

```
public void loadProduct() {
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
try {
     service.create(product);
     logger.info("Creation started");
} catch (Exception e) {
  // Log Exception
     logger.error(e);
}
}
```

I have almost figured out how to achieve this with the help of Spring context:

```
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="1"/>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="productTask" method="loadProduct" cron="0/30 * * * * *"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

But how to schedule the task to start every 24 hours on 11 am every day?

Or is there a way to achieve this in Java code?

Comment: you could create a timer or some daemon thread that checks the system time every x seconds (or a time on a server)

Comment: You appear to have a utility that lets you run cron jobs.  The crux of your question is about learning how to write cron jobs, which would be better learned from a man page about them.

Comment: you can use http://corntab.com/; consider that spring scheduler has seconds while crontab does not. So there are 5 (*) in crontab and 6 in spring scheduler

Comment: "0 0 11 * * *" = 11 o'clock of every day.

Comment: as @Nonika says just have a runnable jar and execute it on the Cron

Comment: Related question: [java - Spring cron expression for every day 1:01:am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147044/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how to schedule the task to start every 24 hours on 11 am every day?

This can be achieved by using the cron expression: `0 0 11 * * *`.

> Or is there a way to achieve this in Java code?

Yes, by using the [`Scheduled` (Spring Framework 5.0.1.RELEASE API)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotation, for example:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 11 * * *", zone = "Europe/Moscow")
public void run() {
    // ...
}
```

Additional references:

1. [Integration: 7. Task Execution and Scheduling: 7.4. Annotation Support for Scheduling and Asynchronous Execution, Spring Framework Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support).
2. [Getting Started · Scheduling Tasks](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/).