# How to use spring @Scheduled with cron for execute every X weeks?

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduling

I want to create a  job that runs every x weeks and on a sundays. I tried to use cron, but I'm not sure that this will work.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * SUN/6")
public void takeAction() {
    LOG.info(LocalDateTime.now().toString());
}
```

Comment: use this as reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147044/spring-cron-expression-for-every-day-101am

Comment: Hello TheTOXIN, welcome to stackoverflow.