# I want to execute Job on 8:00 AM and 3:10 Pm Every Day using Scheduled in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-scheduled

I m using @Scheduled in spring which will work fine if i want to execute task on evey 5 Second using @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
But I want to execute Job on  8:00 AM and 3:10 Pm Every Day which is not working.
Following is My code.

```
@Component
public class FinanceJob  {

    @Autowired
    AdminService adminService;

    @Autowired
    AdminDao dao;

    @Autowired
    CommonService cservice;


    //@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)

    // @Scheduled(cron = "0/20 * * * * ?")
    @Scheduled(cron="0 48 2 * * *",zone = "Indian/Maldives")
    public void sajan() {
        List<SystemParameter> paramList=cservice.getSysParam();

        for(SystemParameter param :paramList)
        {
            if(param.getUid()==263 && param.getIsactive()==1)
            {
                System.out.println("Hello Sahjan");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: what have you tried to execute Job on 8:00 AM and 3:10 Pm Every Day

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot schedule job by two `cron` schedule.

What you can do is wrap your task and expose schedule by another function:

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 8 */1 * *",zone = "Indian/Maldives")
public void schedule1() {
   sajan();
}

@Scheduled(cron="0 10 15 */1 * *",zone = "Indian/Maldives")
public void schedule2() {
   sajan();
}

public void sajan() {

    // yOur task
}
```

Comment: @Scheduled(cron="0 0 5 ? * * *",zone = "Indian/Maldives")
 public void schedule4() {
    sajan();
 }  this will not work. set schedule at 5 o'clock

Comment: `0 0 5 */1 * * *` is the cron for 5AM daily, `0 0 17 */1 * * *` is the cron for 5PM daily

Comment: Thanks.can you please share reference that how to generate cron online.any web site?

Comment: You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147044/spring-cron-expression-for-every-day-101am)

Comment: It's shows error that i will require only 6 parameters and in your code there are 7 parameters.//9 AM daily
 //@Scheduled(cron="0 0 9 * * ?",zone = "Indian/Maldives")
 public void schedule4() {
  System.out.println("SendFinanceEmail Scheduler is called...");
  SendFinanceEmailController();
 }
Above Code is Not Working.
I got  reference from https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html#cronexpressionexamples