# Spring scheduled cron job running too many times

Tags: spring-boot, cron, spring-scheduled

My job is running every at the time specified but its running every second of time specified, for example if I set a job to run at 22:54 it will run every second from 22:54:00 until 22:54:59. I want it to just run once at the time specified...any help is much appreciated

my code:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* 54 22 * * ?")
    public void getCompaniess() {
         System.out.println(new Date()+" > Running testScheduledMethod...");

    }
```

output:

`Thu Mar 12 22:54:00 GMT 2020 > Running testScheduledMethod...
Thu Mar 12 22:54:01 GMT 2020 > Running testScheduledMethod...
.....
Thu Mar 12 22:54:59 GMT 2020 > Running testScheduledMethod...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the first * to 0, with a star you are saying "every second".

Replacing it with a 0 (or any other number 0-59) will have it run on that "second" instead of "all of them".

Comment: This worked, I've been pulling my hair our trying to figure out the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0 54 22 * * ?")
public void getCompaniess() {
    System.out.println(new Date()+" > Running testScheduledMethod...");
}
```

Comment: Here you can find another samples of schedule: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147044/spring-cron-expression-for-every-day-101am