# SpringBoot Scheduler Cron over running

Tags: spring-boot, scheduler

is there any expert having the issue using springboot scheduler

trying to set it to run between 2pm til 10pm on weekday every 15mins/per hour, but it seem like trigger by minute, is that because my cron is wrong or i shld do smthg to control it ?

> running in linux server via springboot-web-started

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 14-22 * * MON-FRI")
private void fireDownload() {
    log.info("fireDownload");

    this.jmsXXXX.run(Constants.XXXX);
}
```

version

> ```
> spring-boot 2.4.2
> java 11
> ```

[image]

Comment: If you have the quartz schedular underneath (which should be the default). Please try "0 0/15 14-22 ? * MON-FRI". You cannot set both the day of month and the day of week indicators, which you are.

Comment: @GerbenJongerius: Tested your suggestion as well, no difference. Please see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */15 14-22 * * MON-FRI")
```

You say in a comment that this is not working, so let's test this with a simple proof-of-concept that fires every 5 minute

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */5 8-22 * * MON-FRI")
private void cronPOC() {
    log.info("cronPOC triggered by cron");
}
```

Screen-shot below shows that the POC is indeed working.

[image]

While we're at testing, let's put @GerbenJongerius suggestion from comment above to the test as well (with some tiny changes in order to speed things up).

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 8-22 ? * MON-FRI")
private void cronPOC() {
    log.info("cronPOC triggered by cron v2");
}
```

... and this is also working
[image]

Some Spring cron examples with explanations here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26147143/14072498

Comment: thanks, i tried the example u share and also read the link u share, there is not helpful for my case as job keep trigger every minutes not same as the setting 0/15 or */15 or 15

Comment: @Kim: Please see my updated answer with a proof-of-concept. Please try the same at your side. BR

Comment: ok great, i found my problem that not because of the cron, that happen when schedule method is create in another class which is not in Springboot  application main class....

when i compare this both, it happen 6 times duplicated running in my component class but the schedule method in main class which just work fine

Comment: @Kim: Good to hear that you found the error, I suspected something like this. Please close the issue by accepting my answer. BR