# Invalid @Scheduled method

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron

It's my first time using the annotation `@Scheduled` and i need it to repeat the code evry hour from 8to20 from monday to friday, so i used one of the multiple cron generator online and this is what came out :

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 8-20 ? * MON-FRI *")
public void deleteExpiredSlots() {
    //my code here
}
```

i get this error  `Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 7 in "0 0 8-20 ? * MON-FRI *")`

I removed the `?` and the error changed to `Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'deleteExpiredSlots': For input string: "MON" 'MON-FRI' in cron expression "0 0 8-20 * MON-FRI *"`

Someone knows what's the problem and possibly how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seven parameter CRON expression is only supported as of Spring 5.3.  Prior to this, you should use this 6 parameter version:

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 8-20 * * MON-FRI")
public void deleteExpiredSlots() {
    // your code here
}
```

The above will fire at the top of the hour from 8am to 8pm inclusive, on weekdays.

Comment: Thanks but what' s the meaning of those  ` * `  ,  between hours and days of the week ...  I found online that the cron structure is something like this : 
 ` (  seconds   minutes   hours   days   months    years )` ....

Is this wrong ?

Comment: The two `*` in my CRON expression mean, respectively, day of month, and month.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147044/spring-cron-expression-for-every-day-101am) for more information.