# Setting CronTrigger quartz job once per day does not work linux server

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I need the job to be performed once a day during the week starting at 01:00 a.m. in the morning.

The application is packaged as a jar.

Running on windows as java -jar on the App it works normally by starting the job at the time reported in the CronTrigger.

Running on the linux server the application seems to loop in running every second.

**Quartz Dependency Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>quartz</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**
This version is being used because the server runs java 1.4. The most current versions of quartz have generated errors while running the app**

I tried the cron expression to run once at 1 am from Monday to Friday. **(0 0 1 ? * MON-FRI)**

I tried every day at 00:00 **(0 0 0 ? * * *)**

**Ref:** cron generator https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

**Class**

```
package com.everis.centers;

import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.quartz.CronTrigger;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

import com.everis.centers.job.ExecuteJob;

public class ExportsApplication {

    private static final String PERIOD = "0 0 1 ? * MON-FRI";
    private static final String PERIOD_2 = "0 0 0 ? * * *";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            Scheduler scheduler = sf.getScheduler();

            JobDetail job = new JobDetail("exportJob", "vj1", ExecuteJob.class);
            CronTrigger ct = new CronTrigger("exportTrigger", "vt1", PERIOD);
            ct.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));

            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, ct);
            scheduler.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you use the expression cron **(0 * / 2 *? * *)** to run every 2 minutes a day. It works normal.
I do not understand the reason for the problem of not only performing once a day at 1am in the morning. If anyone can help, I've cleared all the documentation.

**Obs**

What I realized was, when the execution time is reached it gets executed in loop. That is, if I set to run 1 o'clock in the morning from that time it gets executed in loop. Instead of running once and waiting for the next day.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html), you can understand the significance of each value in Cron expression. If you need to run a job at 12AM every day, try using this expression `0 0 0 * * * *`. This will run job every `00:00` hour every day and only once. If you want to understand the importance of using `?`, you can refer this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23431887/4704236)

Let me know if you face any issues.

You can try [Crontab](https://crontab.guru/) which use UNIX style of cron (no seconds support). If you need to specify seconds as well, you can refer [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html).