# Cron Job With Quartz.net? How To do certain hours of the day?

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am trying to create a cron job that happens every single days 3 times a day at certain times a day.

I thought this is would be how you do it but it gives me

```
System.FormatException: 'Hour values must be between 0 and 23'


  ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule("00 14,17,20 1-31 1-12 *").InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Utc))
            .ForJob("job", "group1")
            .Build();
```

Comment: hey can you please add your crontab code so that I can help.

Comment: You hour value is now 1-31, you have typed two zeroes together (seconds and minutes).

Comment: Like Marko Lahma said, you must separate your seconds and minutes and you can omit the days and months: `0 0 14,17,20 ? * * *`

Comment: @Rabban - what is the question mark for?

Comment: [Significance of question mark in Java cron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23431887/6666799)

Comment: @Rabban - I updated my code to what you have but is my cron job correct that it should run every day at the hours of 14, 17, 20 hundred hours?